# Play2 Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: scala

I am sitting behind a firewall, so I cannot connect to the external repositories to download the necessary files for the Play sample project and then eclipsify.
Is there any other way I can create a Play2 project in Eclipse, like an installable Eclipse plugin to do the work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what are your constraints, but if you can download a zip file, you should try the [Typesafe Activator](http://www.typesafe.com/platform/getstarted). It can generate Eclipse or IntelliJ project files.

You might want to install the Eclipse plugin for [Play2](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-ide-play2) and the [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org).

Comment: My constarints are Timeout happening when I am running the play command and I cannot clone a project from Github and I cannot a push my project into Github. So I am almost stuck.

Comment: I have Scala IDE and Play2 plugin, I will download and install  Typesafe Activator.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what contains the Typesafe activator but I think you will still have issues with SBT in the future when you will need to add more dependencies.

This firewall seems unfortunate for any modern development workflow.

Do you think you could try to introduce Nexus in your company? http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/

It's a proxy that takes place between you and an external repository to have more control over the dependencies in your local network.